# cannot do any operation on the ssrs manager

Tags: sql-server, ssrs, sql-server-2016

I have installed a named instance of sql server with reporting services (2016) on my local machine. But in the reporting service manager (the web portal) I cannot perform any operation*. My guess is that there is a problem in connection between reporting service and database, or some permission issues. I have tried for three days and still no success, cause apparently I'm looking at the wrong place. Any help is highly appreciated.

*for example: when I want to uplad an rdl I face this error:

> Could not connect to the server. Please check your network settings and try again later.

I just add some scree shots which give the overview of my settings, but, please tell me if you think adding some more info helps.

[image]

Comment: Could you provide an anonymous screen shot of your permission settings (site permissions and root permissions)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is really strange and I don't know how to explain the reason this solution works, but I state it here because I found this solution after three days! and it may help someone else.

I was accessing the SSRS portal on Google Chrome (as I did before the installation of SQL Server and Reporting Services) but it wasn't working -- It just kept giving me strange pop up messages.

Solution: Use IE! Yes, use IE (finally there is something that IE is good at).

**Edit:** At the moment that I posted this answer I said that I don't know why this trick does the job but after some researches for another problem I concluded that this behaviour of Chrome is because it saves/buffers many settings to serve the pages faster and that's sometimes problematic. **Therefore**, clearing the hole settings (cookies, ...) should solve this problem.